# Redux and Reselect: Using derived data to compute a part of the state

Tags: reactjs, memoization, redux

What is the best approach to use one part of the redux state tree to update another part of the state. In particular, I have a simplified flashcard app example below. We have a list of words maintained by one reducer, and then another part of the state tree is maintained by a quiz reducer, which holds the currently chosen word. I would like the quiz reducer to have access to the list of words, and maybe even a computed (memoized) filtered subset of the words. What is the best approach here?

```js
// The reducer that manages a list of words
function wordsReducer(state = [], action) {
  switch(action.type) {
  ...
  default:
    return state;
  }
};

// text to filter words with
function filterReducer(state = '', action) {
  switch(action.type) {
  case SET_FILTER:
    return action.payload;
  default:
    return state:
  }
};

// we have derived data, which is a list of filtered words
const filteredWordsSelector = createSelector(
  (state) => state.words,
  (state) => state.filter,
  (words, filter) => words.filter(word => word.indexOf(filter) >= 0)
);

//return one word randomly.
function chooseWord(words) {
  return words[Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length)];
}
```

Here is my confusion below. How can I access computed data inside another 
branch of the state. Also, I want to add complexity to this, like sorting
the words into buckets, which is why I thought reselect (or some other memoization) would be a good approach.

The following answer suggests that I should not use reselect inside my reducers, but is there another approach to my problem?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32922461/2620595

```js
const initialQuizState = {chosenWord: null};

function quizReducer(state = initialQuizState, action, filteredWords) {
  switch(action.type) {
  case CHOOSE_WORD:
    // I want to choose a word at random from filteredWords
    return {...state, chosenWord: chooseWord(filteredWords)};
  default:
    return state;
}

function rootReducer(state, action) {
  return {
    words: wordsReducer(state.words, action),
    filter: filterReducer(state.filter, action),
    quiz: quizReducer(state.quiz, action, filteredWordsSelector(state))
  }
};
```

What is a good approach to organizing my redux reducers? Should I be passing another part of the state into the `quizReducer` above and is it really bad to use `reselect` in this case?

Comment: Generally you shouldn't store derived data in the actual redux store. Reselect is a great way to still calculate data on the fly but in a performant way.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. In my example above, I don't believe I am storing in the derived data, only using it to update the quiz portion of the state, through the quizReducer. Maybe this is just as bad. What about passing one portion of the state into a reducer for another portion, as a third parameter?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think using `selectWord` in your reducer is a violation of Dan Abramov's advice, since it's not actually a pure selector. The use of `Math.random()` means you're deriving your result from something *other than* state.

A more purist approach might be to simply store the result of `Math.random()` in the state, and derive everything else. Though I hesitate to advocate this, since it has the potential downside of making your code more difficult to understand.

Comment: What if this was more complicated, say for example, if the word was chosen based on more criteria (word difficulty, time since last tested, user priority, etc...), should all these factors in choosing a word really be determined outside of the reducers? Wouldn't that mean that all this state logic now lives in the view layer? I'm still not sure what is the best approach.

Comment: I wasn't advocating putting logic in the view layer. When I said the state, I meant the *Redux* state. Perhaps I should have said store. The point being that the generated random number is an original piece of data. The other criteria you mention would also belong in the store.

Comment: "a violation of Dan Abramov's advice" - what's that advice? where it is? Can you link the source, please :)