# Error when using if, when updating the state in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, variables, if-statement

I wanted to update this variable when the condition is true, but it doesn't let me, thanks

```
 constructor(props){
        super(props);
        var isActive = false;

        this.props.items.map(item => (
                if(item.name == this.props.product.name) {
                    isActive = true;
                }
        ));

        this.state = {
            active: isActive
        };

        console.log(isActive);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);

    }
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console? That doesn't look like valid Javascript syntax, but I don't know if react fixes it up.

Comment: In normal JS you can't have `if` inside parentheses, you should have `{}` around the function body.

Comment: why not `setState`?

Comment: because is in the constructor, we cannot call setState in the constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is, you forgot to use `{}`, If you are using any condition or wants to do some calculation use `{}` and put all the statement inside that. One more thing since you just want to iterate the `array` means not returning anything, so i that case use `forEach` instead of `map`, Use this:

```
this.props.items.forEach(item => { //here
    if(item.name == this.props.product.name) {
          isActive = true;
    }
});
```

Check this code it will produce the same error:

```js
[1,2,3,4].forEach(el=>(
     if(el % 2 == 0)
         console.log(el);
))
```

Check the working example:

```js
[1,2,3,4].forEach(el=>{
         if(el % 2 == 0)
             console.log(el);
})
```

Comment: it should be like this: this.props.items.forEach((item) => { //here
    if(item.name == this.props.product.name) {
          isActive = true;
    }
});

Comment: @Ved didn't get you, what's the difference ? he is using single argument so `()` is not required with `item`. That is useful when someone need the `index` also, means multiple arguments :)

Answer (score 0):

You really aren't passing an 'active' property nor state.  You are trying to set a computed property, much like Ember (see [How to setup Ember like computed properties in Immutablejs and Redux and Flux and React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581567/how-to-setup-ember-like-computed-properties-in-immutablejs-and-redux-and-flux-an)).  This was considered for React and dismissed.

You should just create a function, `isActive()` and call it when needed.  I expect you only need it when rendering a set of individual item components for which isActive is a property.

That said, there are ways of cramming this into a React codebase, but your code will be unmaintainable.